# Comparison between supposedly identical strings failing ' == ' comparison

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to read in a dictionary file into a vector of word objects that I then iterate over and compare the object's word with what was inputted by the user.

However, when the comparison is made in Dictionary::wordFind() with a word that should be identical to a word object's word such as "aa", it fails to make the comparison correctly.

No errors are outputted, the if statement in wordFind() just doesn't come true for some reason.

dictionary.txt

```
aa
acronym for Associate in Arts a college degree granted for successful completion of a two-year course of study in arts or general topics;  Alcoholics Anonymous.
n

aaas
the American Association for the Advancement of Science an organization with headquarters in Washington D.C..
n
```

dictionary.cpp

```
void Dictionary::loadDictionary() {

    ifstream dicFile("dictionary.txt");
    string word, def, type, whitespace;

    if (dicFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!dicFile.eof())
        {
            getline(dicFile, word);
            getline(dicFile, def);
            getline(dicFile, type);
            getline(dicFile, whitespace);
            Word word1(word, def, type);
            wordObjects.push_back(word1);

        }
        dicFile.close();
    }
}

void Dictionary::wordFind(string wordToFind) {

    for (Word test : wordObjects)
    {
        if (test.getWord() == wordToFind)
        {
            cout << "Word found!" << endl;
            cout << "Word: " << test.getWord() << "\n\n" << "Definition: " << "\n" << test.getDef();
        }
    }
    cout << "Word not found" << endl;
}
```

word.cpp

```
Word::Word(string _word, string _def, string _type) {
    word = _word;
    def = _def;
    type = _type;
}

string Word::getWord() {
    return word;
}

string Word::getDef() {
    return def;
}

string Word::getType() {
    return type;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    Dictionary dic;
    dic.loadDictionary();
    if (menuChoice == 1)
    {
        string wordSearch;
        cout << "Please enter your word: " << endl;
        cin >> wordSearch;
        dic.wordFind(wordSearch);
}
```

I've noticed using `cout << wordObjects[2].showWord();` (which will output the word "aaas" as shown in the above dictionary.txt) that the output seems to have spaces between the letters of the word as shown in the link below. 
(I tried to just add the image, but I don't have enough karma. Trust me it won't be a nasty link)
https://i.ibb.co/t4053Tf/12221222222222121212.png

I'm unsure why this is happening and I'm wondering if anyone has any idea why my code would produce this behaviour.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks the Paul Sanders comment about the Unicode characters, I recreated the dictionary.txt but saved it in ANSI and it seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Sounds like `dictionary.txt` might contain Unicode.  How did you create it?

Comment: It was created by my lecturer. I copied the text over from a webpage that loads the dictionary.txt to a page. When I save it to a text file, it warns me that the text is Unicode and that I'm attempting to save in ANSI.

Comment: I just recreated the dictionary.txt but saved it in ANSI and it seems to have fixed my issue. Thank you very much @PaulSanders

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you can simplify the code in `Dictionary::loadDictionary()` by removing `if (dicFile.is_open())` and the corresponding curly braces, changing `while (!dicFile.eof())` to `while (dicFile)`, and removing `dicFile.close();`. `while (dicFile)` will loop as long as the file is in a valid state. That covers both hitting end of file and failing to open in the first place. And closing the file isn't necessary -- the destructor will do that.

Comment: Another issue in `Dictionary::loadDictionary()` is that it doesn't detect invalid input. Suppose the input file, for some reason, has only one line; what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using getline, while this might not be your issue, there might be empty spaces after your words which would also become part of your dictionary. You should use an empty space delimiter when reading from a file.

I suggest outputting a dictionary word in your console first, so that you know it was stored correctly.